# NatBib doesn't show the whole reference list

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am writing my thesis using `natbib` in Overleaf. I also want it to show my whole bibliography, not just the ones I cite. Unfortunately when using `plainnat` is only shows 3 references (even do I cited way more), `unsrtnat` shows the ones I cited but not the whole list. This inconsistency doesn't make sense to me at all, hence I am so confused and can't find my issue.
Weirdly all of the citations are shown in the text but not in the bibliography.

Here part of my code (the whole thing is way too long, I hope I included the relevant part. If not I am very sorry, this is my first time asking a question here :).
Most of the code was provided by the Uni, so I don't know if some packages clash or something.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{latexsym,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}


In the text some citing is happening as \cite{..} and \citep{}


\nocite{*}
\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Here part of my library, that is in the same folder as library.bib.

```
@Article{Barnard2000,
  author   = {Barnard, John and McCulloch, Robert and Meng, Xiao-Li},
  journal  = {Statistica Sinica},
  title    = {Modelling {Covariance} {Matrices} in {Terms} of {Standard} {Deviations} and {Correlations}, with {Application} {To} {Shrinkage}},
  year     = {2000},
  month    = oct,
  pages    = {1281--1311},
  volume   = {10},
  abstract = {The covariance matrix plays an important role in statistical inference, yet modeling a covariance matrix is often a difficult task in practice due to its dimensionality and the non-negative definite constraint. In order to model a co-variance matrix effectively, it is typically broken down into components based on modeling considerations or mathematical convenience. Decompositions that have received recent research attention include variance components, spectral decompo-sition, Cholesky decomposition, and matrix logarithm. In this paper we study a statistically motivated decomposition which appears to be relatively unexplored for the purpose of modeling. We model a covariance matrix in terms of its correspond-ing standard deviations and correlation matrix. We discuss two general modeling situations where this approach is useful: shrinkage estimation of regression co-efficients, and a general location-scale model for both categorical and continuous variables. We present some simple choices for priors in terms of standard deviations and the correlation matrix, and describe a straightforward computational strategy for obtaining the posterior of the covariance matrix. We apply our method to real and simulated data sets in the context of shrinkage estimation.},
  comment  = {here find cov decomposition},
  file     = {Full Text PDF:https\://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Barnard2/publication/228606344_Modelling_Covariance_Matrices_in_Terms_of_Standard_Deviations_and_Correlations_with_Application_To_Shrinkage/links/5416f4c50cf2788c4b35f7e7/Modelling-Covariance-Matrices-in-Terms-of-Standard-Deviations-and-Correlations-with-Application-To-Shrinkage.pdf:application/pdf;ResearchGate Link:https\://www.researchgate.net/publication/228606344_Modelling_Covariance_Matrices_in_Terms_of_Standard_Deviations_and_Correlations_with_Application_To_Shrinkage:},
}

@Article{Higham2002,
  author   = {Higham, Nicholas},
  journal  = {IMA Journal of Numerical Analysis},
  title    = {Computing the {Nearest} {Correlation} {Matrix} - a {Problem} {From} {Finance}},
  year     = {2002},
  month    = oct,
  volume   = {22},
  abstract = {Introduction A correlation matrix is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix with unit diagonal. Correlation matrices occur in several areas of numerical linear algebra, including preconditioning of linear systems and error analysis of Jacobi methods for the symmetric eigenvalue problem (see Davies \& Higham (2000) for details and references). The term `correlation matrix' comes from statistics, since a matrix whose (i, j ) entry is the correlation coefficient between two random variables x i and x j is symmetric positive semidefinite with unit diagonal. It is a statistical application that motivates this work---one coming from the finance industry. In stock research sample correlation matrices constructed from vectors of stock returns are used for predictive purposes. Unfortunately, on any day when an observation is made data are rarely available for all the stocks of interest. One way to deal with this problem is to compute the sample correlations of pairs of stocks using data draw},
  doi      = {10.1093/imanum/22.3.329},
  file     = {ResearchGate Link:https\://www.researchgate.net/publication/2839645_Computing_the_Nearest_Correlation_Matrix_-_a_Problem_From_Finance:;:Masterarbeit/narep369.pdf:PDF},
}
```

Weirdly the Bernard paper gets shown in the Reference, Higham isn't.

I hope this question is understandable and if I am missing something you will need to answer it please let me know (like I said I am very new to asking questions on here).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `natbib` is mostly a citation management package. It does *not* determine which bibliographic entries get included in the bibliography and which ones do not. Let me guess: You first added the instruction `\cite{Barnard2000}` and ran BibTeX. Later on during the writing process, you cited the `Higham2002` piece and re-ran LaTeX but did not re-run BibTeX as well. Is is this guess on target? What happens if you perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: When I try with that document I get both entries mentioned. (And the only warnings I get are because you try to use non-existant keys like "..".) Are you sure you have run LaTeX followed by BibTeX followed by LaTeX after your latest changes?

Comment: I am using Overleaf, hence I just press recompile on there. What do I need to do to run LaTeX and BibTeX in Overleaf?
Weirdly enough when I change the style and just press recompile I can see most of the entries.

Comment: @KatHoff - Overleaf-specific questions should be posed to the Overleaf help desk. I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Oh thank you, I did not know such a thing exists. I'm gonna post it there.